# CSS difference when production vs. development

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I had a CRA application and am using [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29). When I deployed the application into [Netlify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlify), something goes wrong with the style. As you can see on this picture below, the block at behind got cut where it should be stretched all the way down. It does stretch in development, but it goes like this when it was deployed. Even though they had the same styling.

[image]

This is the .jsx file:

#### File *Portofolio.jsx*

```html
<div className={`portofolio-app ${navShown ? "blur" : ""}`}>
  <div className="block-1"></div>
  <div className="block-2"></div>
  <div className="block-3"></div>
  <div className="portofolio">
    <div className="container">
      <Card />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

#### SCSS file

File *portofolio.scss*

```
.portofolio-app {
  @include app;

  .block-1,
  .block-2,
  .block-3 {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }

  ..
  // Some other styling
  ..
}
```

The sample web can be seen at the link below:

[manusiatamvan.netlify.app](https://manusiatamvan.netlify.app)

Comment: What is *"CRA"*?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a height for the card here:

```
.portofolio-app .portofolio .card-app {
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(.64,.57,.67,1.7);
    background-color: #2d4647;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 20px 30px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    height: 240px;
    margin: 2em 8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Remove the declaration `height: 240px;` and see if that fixes the problem.
[image]

Comment: no it didn't, I set the card `height` because I want it to be `240px`. The problem is the `block-` thing

Comment: If the height of the div is set to a fixed number of pixels then it's not going to change. That's why the image inside is cut. I got it to stretch by disabling the height of that div from DevTools. See screenshot in edited answer.

Comment: The only thing I think it's happening is that your CSS code in Prod and Dev are not identical.

Comment: I answered the question above, but why did that happen I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this single line of SCSS wasn't read.

```
@import "../Commons/_template";

.portofolio-app {
  @include app; // => This wasn't read

  .block-1,
  .block-2,
  .block-3 {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }

  ..
  // Some other styling
  ..
}
```

_template.scss

```
@mixin app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;

  &.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

When I set `min-height: 100vh` from an inspect element, it works.

So why did this happen? Why wasn't that line read?

Comment: Follow-up questions do not belong here. [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).